# Apex Invalid type: Schema:OutOfOffice

Tags: apex

I'm creating an Apex Scheduler to check users' leave. Here is the code:

```
public static void dailyLeaveChecker(){
    //Delete current OOO message first
    delete [SELECT Id FROM OutOfOffice];

    //Create new
    List<Leave__c> leaveList = getTodaysLeave();
    if (leaveList.size() > 0)
    { 
        List<OutOfOffice> OOOList = new List<OutOfOffice>();
        for (Leave__c singleLeave : leaveList) {
            Date startDate = singleLeave.StartDate__c;
            string startString = singleLeave.StartDate__c.format();
            Date endDate = singleLeave.EndDate__c;
            string endString = singleLeave.EndDate__c.format();
            
            OutOfOffice o = new OutOfOffice();
            o.UserId = singleLeave.OwnerId;
            o.IsEnabled = true;
            o.StartDate = startDate;
            o.EndDate = endDate;
            o.message = 'Out of Office ' + startString + endString;
            OOOList.add(o);
        }
        insert OOOList;
    }
}
```

It works fine when I push it to my current scratch org. But when I push it to a new empty scratch org, I got this error:

> Class LeaveService : Invalid type: Schema.OutOfOffice

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Feel free to Upvote [Allow enable Out-of-office via scratch org definition file](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZxDUAV/allow-enable-outofoffice-via-scratch-org-definition-file?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) on the IdeaExchange.

Comment: @TSmith Ah this is what I'm looking for. So it's currently not possible? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OutOfOffice` object is available when [Users can set Out of Office messages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_admin_out_of_office.htm&type=5) setting is enabled.

Comment: Is there any way to enable it during scratch org creation? I'm guessing from TSmith's comment it is not possible yet?

Comment: If you know some node, you could automate the enabling of this setting with [puppeteer](https://github.com/wadewegner/sfdx-puppeteer/blob/master/run.js).